# Functions inside Azure ARM Template param files are not been working

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

I am working on an Azure ARM Template that to deploy vNet with route tables and having problem with the routerTable ID reference. It all works when the function is inside the deploy.json. But, When I moved all parameter definition to the param file I started getting error complaining about the property id is invalid

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: - The deployment 'deploy-vnet' failed
> with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: Property
> id '[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', 'Backend')]' at path
> 'properties.subnets[0].properties.routeTable.id' is invalid. Expect
> fully qualified resource Id that start with
> '/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}' or
> '/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/'.
> (Code:LinkedInvalidPropertyId)

Here is the ARM Template:

```
 // Deploy ARM Template
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VNetSettings": { "type": "object" },
        "RouteTables": { "type": "array" }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "[parameters('RouteTables')[copyIndex('routetablecopy')].name]",
            "location": "eastus2",
            "properties": {
                "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false,
                "routes": "[parameters('RouteTables')[copyIndex('routetablecopy')].routes]"
            },
            "copy": {
                "name": "routetablecopy",
                "count": "[length(parameters('RouteTables'))]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[parameters('VNetSettings').name]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[parameters('VNetSettings').addressPrefixes[0].addressPrefix]"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets":"[parameters('VNetSettings').subnets]"

            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "text": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "Hello Testing"
        },
        "routetableoutput": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', 'Backend')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the parameter file I am using:

```
///PARAM FILE
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "VNetSettings": {
            "value": {
                "name": "fd-ARM-vnet",
                "addressPrefixes": [{
                    "name": "firstPrefix",
                    "addressPrefix": "10.15.0.0/16"
                }],
                "subnets": [{
                        "name": "Frontend",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.15.0.0/24",
                            "routeTable": {
                                **"id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', 'Backend')]"**
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Backend",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.15.1.0/24"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "RouteTables": {
            "value": [
            {
                "name": "Backend",
                "routes": [{
                    "name": "To-Internet",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "0.0.0.0/0",
                        "nextHopType": "VirtualAppliance",
                        "nextHopIpAddress": "10.15.1.4"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "Frontend",
                "routes": [{
                    "name": "Local-Subnet",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "10.15.0.0/24",
                        "nextHopType": "VnetLocal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "To-Internal",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "10.15.0.0/16",
                        "nextHopType": "VirtualAppliance",
                        "nextHopIpAddress": "10.15.0.4"
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
    
        }  

    }
}
```

If I create the VNET without the "routeTable" property in the file it works fine but then the routeTable is not attached to the subnet. If I use:
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', 'Backend')]"
or
"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', 'Backend'))]"
I get the same invalid property error message.

Any one know how to address this issue??? Another observation is that the same function works fine in the output section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure function dont work in the parameters file, so your workaround is - calculate them outside (in powershell\python\etc) and edit them into the parameters file, or just calculate them inside the template